Unity Mixer with slider in uxml, Audio volume values ​not persisting after scene reload despite using PlayerPrefs
In Unity, I'm using an Audio Mixer to manage audio volume including Music and SFX. I've implemented UI sliders via UXML and I'm using PlayerPrefs to save and load volume values ​​between sessions. over time I encountered a problem: although the slider values ​​are correctly imported and displayed, the audio volume does not persist after reloading the scene. For example, if I set the music volume to 50% and restart the scene, the volume returns to the default value. I have verified that the values ​​are correctly saved via PlayerPrefs, but it seems that the audio mixer does not apply these values ​​after reloading the scene. I have tried several solutions, but so far without success. How can I solve this problem?
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class VolumeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string sliderTemplateName = "MySlider";
    public AudioMixer musicMixer;
    public AudioMixer sfxMixer;

    private const string musicPrefsKey = "MusicVolume";
    private const string sfxPrefsKey = "SFXVolume";

    private const float minVolumeDB = -80f;
    private const float maxVolumeDB = 0f;

    private Slider musicSlider;
    private Slider sfxSlider;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("Awake called");
        LoadVolumeSettings();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEnable called");

        var uiDocument = GetComponent<UIDocument>();
        if (uiDocument != null)
        {
            var root = uiDocument.rootVisualElement;
            var sliders = root.Query<Slider>(sliderTemplateName).ToList();

            if (sliders.Count >= 2)
            {
                musicSlider = sliders[0];
                sfxSlider = sliders[1];

                musicSlider.RegisterValueChangedCallback(evt => OnMusicVolumeSliderChanged(evt.newValue));
                sfxSlider.RegisterValueChangedCallback(evt => OnSFXVolumeSliderChanged(evt.newValue));

                // Initializing sliders with PlayerPrefs values
                float savedMusicVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(musicPrefsKey, 0.5f);
                float savedSfxVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(sfxPrefsKey, 0.5f);

                musicSlider.SetValueWithoutNotify(savedMusicVolume);
                ApplyMusicVolume(savedMusicVolume);

                sfxSlider.SetValueWithoutNotify(savedSfxVolume);
                ApplySFXVolume(savedSfxVolume);

                Debug.Log($"OnEnable: Loaded music volume: {savedMusicVolume}, SFX volume: {savedSfxVolume}");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("Insufficient sliders found in UXML.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("UIDocument not found on the GameObject.");
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDisable called");
        if (musicSlider != null)
        {
            musicSlider.UnregisterValueChangedCallback(evt => OnMusicVolumeSliderChanged(evt.newValue));
        }
        if (sfxSlider != null)
        {
            sfxSlider.UnregisterValueChangedCallback(evt => OnSFXVolumeSliderChanged(evt.newValue));
        }
    }

    private void LoadVolumeSettings()
    {
        Debug.Log("LoadVolumeSettings called");

        float musicVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(musicPrefsKey, 0.5f);
        float sfxVolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(sfxPrefsKey, 0.5f);

        ApplyMusicVolume(musicVolume);
        ApplySFXVolume(sfxVolume);

        Debug.Log($"LoadVolumeSettings: Loaded music volume: {musicVolume}, SFX volume: {sfxVolume}");
    }

    private void OnMusicVolumeSliderChanged(float volume)
    {
        Debug.Log($"OnMusicVolumeSliderChanged: Volume changed to {volume}");
        SetMusicVolume(volume);
    }

    private void OnSFXVolumeSliderChanged(float volume)
    {
        Debug.Log($"OnSFXVolumeSliderChanged: Volume changed to {volume}");
        SetSFXVolume(volume);
    }

    private void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(musicPrefsKey, volume);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        ApplyMusicVolume(volume);

        Debug.Log($"SetMusicVolume: Music volume saved and applied: {volume}");
    }

    private void SetSFXVolume(float volume)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(sfxPrefsKey, volume);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        ApplySFXVolume(volume);

        Debug.Log($"SetSFXVolume: SFX volume saved and applied: {volume}");
    }

    private void ApplyMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        float musicVolumeDB = Mathf.Lerp(minVolumeDB, maxVolumeDB, volume);
        musicMixer.SetFloat("MusicVolume", musicVolumeDB);
        Debug.Log($"ApplyMusicVolume: Applied music volume: {volume} ({musicVolumeDB} dB)");
    }

    private void ApplySFXVolume(float volume)
    {
        float sfxVolumeDB = Mathf.Lerp(minVolumeDB, maxVolumeDB, volume);
        sfxMixer.SetFloat("SFXVolume", sfxVolumeDB);
        Debug.Log($"ApplySFXVolume: Applied SFX volume: {volume} ({sfxVolumeDB} dB)");
    }

    [ContextMenu("Reset PlayerPrefs")]
    private void ResetPlayerPrefs()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(musicPrefsKey);
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey(sfxPrefsKey);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log("ResetPlayerPrefs: PlayerPrefs for music and SFX volumes have been reset.");
    }
}


I tried using PlayerPrefs to save and load audio volume values ​​between sessions. I expected that after reloading the scene, the audio volume would remain set to the value saved via PlayerPrefs.
